# Quickfix go to next error of specific type

Tags: quickfix, plugin-vim-latex

I am starting to use `quickfix` to handle my latex compilation process. I found the `vim-latex` package (https://github.com/vim-latex/vim-latex) but I am only interested in the quickfix part, and I want to use my own Makefile, so I merely copied https://github.com/vim-latex/vim-latex/blob/master/compiler/tex.vim to my `~/.vim/compiler/` and commented out the part that sets `makeprg`. I also modified

```
if &errorfile ==# ''  ||  &errorfile ==# 'errors.err'
    execute 'set errorfile=' . fnameescape(Tex_GetMainFileName(':p:r') . '.log')
endif
```

to

```
if &errorfile ==# ''  ||  &errorfile ==# 'errors.err'
    execute 'set errorfile=' . fnameescape(expand('%:p:r') . '.log')
endif
```

I also put

```
compiler tex
```

in my `~/.vim/ftplugin/tex.vim`

The quickfix otherwise works fine, a sample quickfix list looks like,

> (a lot of messages from latex log file)  
> |125 error| Undefined control sequence. \R  
>                            ./abstract.tex|| ...  
> (more messages from latex log file) 
> |197 warning| ...

where the `error` is marked with red font and the `./abstract.tex` is marked with light green font. If I go to the buffer containing the source file and execute `:cn`, it jumps to the correct line in the source file with the next error/warning, so I believe `errorformat` is set correctly. `:cn` also works correctly in the quickfix list window, However, pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> in the quickfix list window around `125 error` or `197 warning` does not seem to have any effect. Pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> around `./abstract.tex||` does work though. This is a minor issue that I can live with, but I would still like to know any fix to it.

By the way, `:verbose nmap <CR>` says "No mapping found" in the quickfix window.

My second and main question is as in the sample quickfix list above, there are errors as well as warnings. I am wondering whether there is a way to jump to the next error ignoring all the warnings, and vice versa. In the terminology of `quickfix`, is there a way to jump to the next error of a certain type (`%t` in `errorformat`)? The simple command `:cn` navigates through all the errors, regardless of the type.

Comment: check getqflist(), check returned data, you might find answer to both your problem. You need custom command if you want to skip warning, another option is to tell your compiler to supress warning.

Comment: Thank you. Would you mind making it an answer? `plugin-vim-latex` has options to suppress markup of warnings, I just wanted to know such a function is available in general when I asked this question.

Comment: It's just an advice, you can post the specific answer yourself after you fix both problems.